# Can't find a document from MongoDB by ref id

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have a member in my application like so

```
const member = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  organization: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Organization',
    required: true,
  },
});
```

I struggle to find a member by organization id. Even if I first find a member by id using the following query

```
const member1 = await Member.findById(id).populate('organization')
```

and then try to find the same member using his organization id

```
const member2 = await Member.findOne({organization: member1.organization});
```

member2 comes back as null.

What am I missing? I really can't see why the member2 is null here. member1 organization is also not null. Everything I find about mongodb says that my approach should work, where am I going wrong here?

Solved:
The error occured while I was running tests. My testdata was inserted in the database like

```
  {
    _id: Types.ObjectId('5acdda00ad63c400142c22ec'),
    email: 'email',
    password: 'hash',
    organization: '5ce474e00000000000000000',
  },
```

And shouldve been

```
  {
    _id: Types.ObjectId('5acdda00ad63c400142c22ec'),
    email: 'email',
    password: 'hash',
    organization: Types.ObjectId('5ce474e00000000000000000'),
  },
```